# jquery ajax call question

Tags: jquery, ajax, call

In a jQuery ajax statement I want to receive a payload from the server and process it in another function.  I am just having trouble with the syntax of the function.

```
    $.ajax({
    url: 'mypgm.pgm',
    type:'POST', 
    dataType: 'json',
    data:   'action=add' +
             '&techno=' + techno +
             '&activity=' + activity, 
    success: ajax_callback(msg),
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
        }       
    });
}

    function ajax_callback(msg) { 

        alert(msg);
    }
```

Response

```
{"response": {
    "success": "0",
    "message": "The Activity has been added."
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like `mypgm.php` is responding, per the response you have here - what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A success callback handler for `$.ajax()` can take in the following values:

```
success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
```

Source: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

So your function callback would be something like this:

```
function ajax_callback(data, textStatus, jqXHR)     
{
  alert(data.response)
}
```

Note how I created a named function this way, instead of assigning it to a var. If you only care about the data, you can just leave the last 2 parameters off:

```
function ajax_callback(data)     
{
  alert(data.response)
}
```

Comment: Does this look like this? success: success(data, textStatus, jqXHR),

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. The format of a callback handler for success is just as you have pasted, and just as I have laid out in my code. Please give it a try and let me know if you have an issue.

Comment: @bob data is simply a parameter of the function ajax_callback. You could call it anything you wanted within the rules of javascript variable names. It could be cow, dog, lemon, whatever you want. What gives it a value is that the JQuery `$.ajax` code, upon successful completion of an AJAX code, passes the data, the text status, and the ajax object to the callback you defined.

Comment: @bob In turn, data gets assigned the data, textStatus gets assigned the text status, and jqXHR gets assigned the value of the ajax object.

Comment: Hi onteria - thanks for your patients. I revised my original example above. however I still get 'msg not defined error'

Comment: @bob `success: ajax_callback(msg)` This is the issue, you don't need the (msg) after it. Just do `success: ajax_callback`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'mypgm.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: 'action=add' + '&techno=' + techno + '&activity=' + activity,
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data)
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I would like break the success function out.

Answer (score 0):

You callback should be defined before the ajax call and change the signature of the function to:

```
var ajax_callback = function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
    // parse the data.responseText to json
}
```

You could alternatively just use `$.getJSON()`

Comment: not sure if we are sticking with json. .ajax seems more flexible.